# Async loaded data won't be rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I´ve got async data loaded via jayson from an server. When finished loading the bool "loading" is set to false, but my content is not rerendered.
I can see on the console that the data was loaded correctly.

```js
var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'test',
    data: [],
    loading: true
  },
  created() {
    this.getProjectDataFromServer()
  },
  methods: {
    getProjectDataFromServer() {
      client.request('get', null, function(err, response) {
        if(err) throw err;
        this.data = response.result;
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.data);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<main id='app'>
  <div v-if="loading===false" :key="loading">
    IT WORKS
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: The meaning of `this` is different inside your callback method where it points to the `Event` object rather than the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lambda instead of function to capture the context of `this`.

```
getProjectDataFromServer() {
      client.request('get', null, (err, response) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        this.data = response.result;
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.data);
      });
    }
```

Or capture the `this` context in a closure outside of the function.

```
getProjectDataFromServer() {
      const that = this;
      client.request('get', null, function (err, response) {
        if(err) throw err;
        that.data = response.result;
        that.loading = false;
        console.log(that.data);
      });
    }
```